# How come this ETH wallet has transactions but 0 in fees?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, gas, etherscan

This might be a stupid question but as far as I knew as soon as you send a transaction on ethereum you pay a transaction fee. However this wallet has a total of 1,388,802 transactions but 0 in fees.

This is the wallet
0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2

Answer (score 1):

The address [0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code) belong to a contract.

Contracts don't pay fees, users invoking them pay the transactions fees.

In this particular case the contract is WETH. It is used to wrap ETH as an ERC20 token. It is used by several exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an aside, because it's not clear what you're asking. (I see lots of transactions involving that contract, all of them with a fee in the last column [once they move from 'pending' state].)

> This might be a stupid question but as far as I knew as soon as you send a transaction on ethereum you pay a transaction fee

Not necessarily.

You can submit a transaction with a gas price of 0. It's up to the miners whether or not to mine it into a block. The chances of such a transaction getting into a block will depend on the state of the gas market - i.e. how congested the network is.

Answer (score 0):

submit a transaction with a gas price of 0. It's up to the miners whether or not to mine it into a block. The chances of such a transaction getting into a block will depend on the state of the gas market - i.e. how congested the network is.